# Is a rear wheel with a Shimano 105 hub compatible with a 8 speed cassette?

Tags: frames, compatibility, parts

Hi Bicycles Stack Exchange!

I ride a Specialized Allez 2020 and looking to replace the rear wheel.  Is a rear wheel with a Shimano 105 hub compatible with the 8 speed cassette the Allez comes with?

Your help would be much appreicated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but unless it's an older 105 wheel (FH-5700 or earlier, but not FH-5800, FH-R7000, or later), it will be an 11-speed freehub, and so running it with an 8-speed cassette requires a 1.85mm spacer.

Most current road repair/replacement/upgrade wheels are like this unless you get down to the very lowest price points, so adding one of these spacers is a normal thing and shops should have them. Some wheels will come with it and some won't, but it's always the same 1.85mm thickness, and any brand's version of it will work.